# Can I use Allure Reporter in JS without any framework to create customize reports?

Tags: javascript, testing, nightwatch.js, allure

I am using nightwatch js as my testing framework. I want to use allure reporter but with full control over report generation. How can I use allure reporter js to create custom reports ? How can I use it to just add test step according to my step definition ?